# RxJS throwError event not directed to handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs

Trying to [build a login demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-login-logout-slice-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauth.service.ts) and IIUC the second argument to `login` should be receiving the result of `throwError`, but it is not.  Any ideas:

```
  login(username: string, password:string) {
    this.authenticate(username, password).subscribe(
      user => {
        this.ostore.put(USER_KEY, user);
        this.ostore.put(AUTHENTICATION_ERROR_KEY, false);
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }),
      (error)=>{
        console.log("Storing the Error");
        error => this.ostore.put(AUTHENTICATION_ERROR_KEY, AUTHENTICATION_ERROR_MESSAGE);
      }
  }


  private authenticate(username:string, password:string) {
  // Mock Authentication Check
  if (username !== 'user') {
      return throwError(AUTHENTICATION_ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
  return of({ name: username });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the second argument but the second callback of susbscribe which receives the errror. Have your "login" like this:

```
login(username: string, password:string) {
  this.authenticate(username, password).subscribe(
    user => {
      this.ostore.put(USER_KEY, user);
      this.ostore.put(AUTHENTICATION_ERROR_KEY, false);
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    },
    error => {
      console.log("Storing the Error");
      error => this.ostore.put(AUTHENTICATION_ERROR_KEY, AUTHENTICATION_ERROR_MESSAGE);
    })
}
```

See it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-login-logout-slice-demo-knrdjs?file=src/app/auth.service.ts

Comment: Awesome - Just realized I had misplaced the first parenthesis - Thanks!

Comment: @Ole: Haha, yeah it happens!